# Which dimensionality reduction technique for mixed data?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, mixed-type-data

I have a binary dependent variable and 18 independent variables which I want to use as regressors in a logistic regression. Prior to that, I want to reduce the dimensionality of the data set to shield my model against overfitting. Which dimensionality reduction technique do you recommend me given that 8 regressors are categorical, 1 is ordinal scaled, 9 are count variables and 1 is interval scaled? The size of the data set is roughly 50000. I'm working with RStudio.

Comment: How many levels are your 8 categorical variables?

Comment: How many cases in each dependent variable category? How do you intend to use your model after it is built? Penalizing rather than completely excluding predictors might be better.

Comment: homals ("homogeneity analysis") is a method for dimensionality reduction with mixed variables.  See this:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-categorical-variables/108028#108028    for some ideas.

Comment: @Lan_Fin: 6 / 8 are binary, the other two have 3 levels each.

Comment: @EdM: the ordinal scaled variable has 5 levels; most of the 9 count variables have roughly 15 levels; the discrete interval scaled variable has roughly 50 levels. The model shall be used to predict the dependent variable. What do you exactly mean by "penalizing"?

Comment: Of the 50000 cases, how many are in each of the 2 classes? The risk of over-fitting is related to the number of cases in the smaller class, compared against the number of predictors. Also, how you planning on incorporating the count variables into the regression?

Comment: Penalization refers to methods that restrict regression coefficients to lower absolute values than they would have in a standard regression. This is a major way to minimize over-fitting. Penalization includes LASSO, ridge regression, and their combination in what's called elastic net. See for example [this summary](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats203/notes/penalized.pdf).