# Transforming Categorical (a.k.a. Nominal) data to Bernoulli Variables

Tags: categorical-data, modeling, bernoulli-process

I've been doing some multivariate analysis for a dataset that contains, for the most part, categorical data. For example, I have two which are:

1. gender (M or F)
2. state (A, B or C)

and each observation is a person.

With the objective of finding correlation between gender and state, my first naive attempt was to create dummy variables that act as indicators. Hence, I created 5 columns: $gender_M$, $gender_F$, $state_A$, $state_B$, $state_C$. To illustrate, if an entry was:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
person & gender & state \\
\hline
rick & M &B \\
\hline
\end{array}

it became:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
person & gender_M & gender_F & state_A & state_B & state_C \\
\hline
rick & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

To my understanding, I'm creating 5 Bernoulli random variables (one for each new column). Hence, I can now apply traditional methods to calculate expectation, covariance, correlation and etc.

The thing is: **is this wrong in some sense?** The model looks ok to me. **Am I missing out on something that would allow me to extract better insights from my data?** Is it wrong to expect Pearson's Correlation to give me good results (literature says to use Cramér's V)?

Thanks!

Comment: Following your example, it seems to me that your question is about the correlation between two categorical variables, and transforming these variables is just a step to accomplish this (so in this sense, the title is not very informative). As you can see in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112674/109647), if you are looking for a test of significance of the association between these two categorical (nominal) variables and a measure of strength of their association, chi-squared test and Cramer’s V (as you mentioned at the end) might be enough.

Comment: They're *binary* variables, not Bernoulli. Bernoulli relates to a probability distribution, while these needn't be random. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: @Glen_b right, I phrased it wrong. My thought was: I can model my dataset as a multivariate Bernoulli R.V.

Comment: @T.E.G. my actual question was regarding to thinking of my transformed dataset as a multivariate Bernoulli variable. The correlation talk was just to illustrate the results I could obtain if my thoughts were correct.