# How to measure the association/correlation between two unordered category distributions

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, python, association-measure

I have seen the questions like [Correlations with unordered categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-unordered-categorical-variables)
, but I cannot implement the chi-square test since I don't have a chi-square table representing joint distribution. Besides, It was said that distance metrics like Euclidean distance is not reasonable. Currently, I just have several 1*n data, which are discrete variables or I can use their Gumbel softmax distribution approximation.

How can I test the association of those unordered category distributions? 
PS: For example, one data is [0.1 0.5 0.3 0.1], another one is [0.2 0.5 0.1 0.2]. Actually, they are quite similar if we sort them and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I decided to use the JSD divergence.