# Categorical and Numerical Features - Correlation

Tags: correlation, python, categorical-data, scikit-learn

I am working with a dataset that has both numerical and categorical features. I have seen this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-unordered-categorical-variables?newreg=c55f23ab4aa74001b0e202aa9a275ee8) which discusses the problem in R, and was wondering if someone could recommend the same in [Scikitlearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

I am trying to find the best way to examine the correlation among all of the features in my dataset. Currently, I am only able to see the numeric features, for example, using the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) library,

```
 c = data.corr()
 sns.heatmap(c, annot=True, cmap='Greens')
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try `pandas.factorize` to get the numerical representation of the categorical variables. Then you can use `data.corr()` to get the correlation among all the features(numerical and categorical).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

You might want to read this post "The search for categorical correlation by Shaked Zychlinski" on towardsdatascience blog, https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9

I hope this helps.